# Is it possible to switch out the voice for the Talkback-reader?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

Can you switch out the voice of the Talkback-reader completely?

In car-navigationsystems you can download "funny" or different sounding persons (male, female, actor, ...).

But the for the Talkback-reader you can only change the pitch and speed that it should use.

I am not sure if Talkback is using voice-samples internally, which would make it necessary to record a real person like an actor speaking. Or if Talkback is using synthesized speech, with which parameters you can fiddle around.

So can you change the voice of the Talkback-reader? For instance into a funny voice, or Hawking-like, or your own, ...?